# Use SSO to connect to SQL Server DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, blazor, single-sign-on

I've managed to get SSO working with a Server side Blazor website I've been writing. I now need to connect to a SQL Server DB with the active user. I want to avoid using a SQL login if I can help it as that limits my ability to restrict DB access intuitively by user. Using Windows Authentication defaults to an Anonymous login for the DB connection.

How do I connect to the DB as if it were via Windows Authentication?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by

> limits my ability to restrict DB access intuitively by user

?

Because what you're describing here isn't what is usually done. The logic behind what which user can see is very domain specific and doing a generic solution using database built-in mechanisms (as row-level-security) may not work for you in just a little more complex scenarios than simple "this row can be viewed by this user".

I'd suggest rolling out your own mechanism (which may be just a check inside stored procedure to see if user can see specific data).

Regarding question, what I do is to replace (in connection string) login and password part with `Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False`. This enables windows authentication. I'm not sure what `Persist Security Info` does, but I keep it not to break things :-)

Comment: Yeah I thought that "intuitive" phrase was a bit naff. I just want to control user access via DB roles and so forth without having to do coding changes. I've tried the SSPI connection string but still get an anonymous login. Is there anything else I need to set up?

Comment: Woah. Just occured to me. Your application is running (generally) as an app pool user if you're hosting it in IIS, or some other assigned user, if you're doing some self-hosted scenario. And that user is used for database logging when in windows authentication mode. You could use Impersonate() (for .NET Framework: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate?view=netframework-4.8.1, for .NET 6: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#impersonation).